# Using Python, how to stop the screen from updating its content?

Tags: python, screen, freeze, display

I searched the web and SO but did not find an aswer.
Using Python, I would like to know how (if possible) can I stop the screen from updating its changes to the user.
In other words, I would like to buid a function in Python that, when called, would freeze the whole screen, preventing the user from viewing its changes. And, when called again, would set back the screen to normal. Something like the Application.ScreenUpdating Property of Excel VBA, but applied directly to the whole screen.
Something like:
FreezeScreen(On)
FreenScreen(Off)
Is it possible?
Thanks for the help!!

Comment: This is not a 'normal' part of UI frameworks and there is no built-in primitive function. Also, you'll probably want to specify *which* UI [framework] "the screen" represents.

Comment: Take a screen shot, open in a full screen viewer?

Comment: @user2864740, thank you! Since it is not as trivial, I think I will give up. That was just a cosmetic thing, not stricly necessary to the app I am buiding.

Comment: @kindall, thank you! You had an clever idea, but I think I will give up from this, since it is not trivial, and it would be just for cosmetic, not obligatory to my app. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by "the screen" you're talking about the terminal then I highly recommend checking out the curses library. It comes with the standard version of Python. It gives control of many different aspects of the terminal window including the functionality you described.

Comment: thank you! I will take a look at the curses library. But I am using a graphical interface terminal (Microsoft Windows), and it seems that the curses library was made towards text terminals only. But maybe it can help indeed. Thank you!